# Hyperledger composer commands not working

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I'm going through the Composer tutorials available here - https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/developer-tutorial. I believe this is the official documentation.

The steps and commands listed in the developer tutorial - Deploying the business network is not working. All the steps and commands listed in this section are deprecated I think. Where can I find the latest documentation?

Comment: What version of Composer are you using?  What version of Hyperledger Fabric?  What is the error you are seeing ?

Comment: In order to help you, we need more information - you should follow this format when submitting a Hyperledger Composer question -> https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-knowledge-wiki/blob/latest/knowledge.md#information_source--creating-a-problem-report-issue thanks.

Comment: I was able to resolve all the issues by jumping to a different section in the tutorials - https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-single-org

Answer (score 0):

To give little more background, the commands failing in the developer tutorial are

*composer runtime install --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --businessNetworkName tutorial-network*

*composer network start --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw --archiveFile tutorial-network@0.0.1.bna --file networkadmin.card*

--card is not a parameter anymore I think, not sure though.
Composer version - v0.16.3
Operating System/version - MacOS High Sierra

Solution - skipped to tutorial deploy business network to single org https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-single-org

The steps listed in this tutorial helped me create the necessary network cards with the certificate and connection profile. These were required to successfully deploy the business network in my local fabric.

Hope this helps.